# How to update cell value automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use google app script to setFormula() 
to set cell value like `"=importxml()"`

I use `importxml()` to get the html data.

But there is something wrong that it does'nt update data automatically.

And I found some way to solve the problem.

The trigger class I found from the [google developer guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers),
and use the function to update every minute.

Function do it actually,but data didn't changed as html data changed.

And I found the other way.
On google-sheet setting to set the calculation.
But there is in vain.
[image]

What should I do to solve the problem?

And is there some detail I ignored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `importhtml()` and `importxml()` function there is some cache on Google server and 2 request in a short time do not trigger a real query to URL.

Way to force that is to add a #random value at the URL, for example https://example.com#randomnumber

Random number can be the random() formula of sheets.

Unfortunately by experience when you have an import function and a script you can't be sure it will be updated when script will run even if you add a `spreadsheetApp.flush()`

From my point of view you will not have something really functional you can trust. On this kind of case solution recommended would be to use `urlFetch()` and do the job in apps script.

Comment: I use the Math.random() after the url to workaround. Very appreciate it.

Comment: Great, happy to help you :-)